# Issue with retrofit post call with json parameter

Tags: android, json, rest, post, retrofit

I have a problem with the following post URL call:

```
https://url?filter={"text":"*"}&response_format=object
```

I get 406 HTTP code but when calling in postman it's OK. If anyone could help me I would appreciate

Comment: Can you show what your Retrofit code actually looks like?

Comment: @BrianYencho 


@Headers("Accept:application/json; Authorization:xxxxxx")
    @POST("/search")
    fun getCardInfo(@Query("filter") filter: String,
                    @Query("response_format") response_format: String): Call<KanbanResponseEntity>

Comment: OK and how are you passing the JSON string for the "filter" variable? Is it a raw string using triple quotes, like """{"text":"*"}"""?

Comment: I found the solution, It was really strange... I deleted "Accept: application/json" from the header and it worked like a charm! Strange part is that the company tolled me to add "Accept: application/json" in the document!!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.